# Fetch all SQL query into an array at a time?

Tags: php, sql

Well, the php code below successfull adds up all the rows in the `url` field.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE url <> ''";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$sql_num = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($sql_row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    urls[] = $sql_row["url"];
}
```

The problem is that if the list of url are in millions, then it takes a lot of time (especially in localhost). So, I'd like to know anothe way of getting the sql query result directly into an array without using a loop. Is it possible?

Comment: PHP is not intended to hand multi-megabytes worth of data in memory. It's **NOT** memory-efficient. What exactly are you planning on doing with this data? Could you not do whatever manipulation you need in the SQL query itself?

Comment: Do you actually need all those million rows, are you showing those million rows to the user? If so, why, i feel you are not telling us everything here, such as a pagination issue or a missing knot in the query such as a condition to filter out some rows...

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using mysqli for that purpose. The `fetch_all()` method would allow to do that.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

**UPDATE**

As per comments, I tried both methods. I tried using `mysql_fetch_array` in a loop, and using `mysqli::fetch_all()` method, on a large table we have in production. `mysqli::fetch_all()` did use less memory and ran faster than the `mysql_fetch_array` loop.

The table has about 500000 rows. `mysqli::fetch_all()` finished loading the data in an array in 2.50 seconds, and didn't hit the 1G memory limit set in the script. `mysql_fetch_array()` failed from memory exhaustion after 3.45 seconds.

Comment: ... and would still be slow - sucking millions of rows into a PHP array is going to crawl no matter WHAT db library you use.

Comment: @MarcB Absolutely. The question was about loading all rows in an array without a loop. I'm not saying it's a miracle solution ;)

Comment: @MathieuImbert The problem was relative to loading a million rows without taking seconds to read the data...

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin I completely agree. And I believe that using mysqli instead of mysql and using `fetch_all()` will be beneficial performance-wise.

Comment: I acknowledge that mysqli is probably more efficient because it runs on optimized C code, but fetching a million rows into memory is madness however you look at it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the loop, it's that you are transferring millions of pieces of data (possibly large) from your database into memory. Whichever way you're doing that, it'll take time. And somebody needs to loop somewhere anyway.

In short: reduce the amount of data you get from the database.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` is deprecated, and the functionality you want is found in `mysqli` and `PDO`. It's the perfect excuse to switch to the newer MySQL extensions. For both `mysqli` and `PDO`, the method is `fetchAll` (note that the `mysqli::fetch_all` requires the `mysqlnd` driver to run).

Answer (score 0):

there is no option for it in mysql. though you can use pdo's fetchall()

http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchall